# Prove that $C(a)$ is closed with respect to $*$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Assume that $*$ is an associative operation on $S$ and that $a \in S$.
>
> Let $C(a) = \{x: x \in S\text{ and } a*x = x*a\}$.
>
> Prove that $C(a)$ is closed with respect to $*$.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, you will usually get much better answers if you ask a question rather than give an assignment and state what you have tried.

Comment: Ok, I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_1,x_2\in C(a)$. Then $$x_1*a=a*x_1,x_2*a=a*x_2$$ We want to show that $x_1*x_2\in C(a).$ We have:
$$(x_1*x_2)*a=x_1*(x_2*a)=x_1*(a*x_2)=(x_1*a)*x_2=(a*x_1)*x_2=a*(x_1*x_2)$$ This is what you need.

Comment: short and sweet!

Comment: Why do they tell me the a*x=x*a part? To tell me that it's commutative?

Comment: Bull, the operation may *not* be commutative --- but if $x$ is in $C(a)$, then $x$ and $a$ commute, and you can see where that was used, twice, in the proof.